# Mailing out a customised content based on specific search in a logfile

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed, logs, search

Using below `test.sh`, I am getting result in `dump.txt` as below:

**test.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash

#"Maxl-script" zone starts.....
essmsh -l admin password -s localhost -i << EOF

spool on to 'dump.txt';
display session all;
spool off;

EOF
#"Maxl-script" zone ends.....
```

**dump.txt:**

```
user                session             login_time          application         database            db_connect_time     request             request_time        connection_source   connection_ip       request_state
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------
 admin                                 0                   9                                                           0 none                                  0 Not Requested*      a00:bf32::                    
 admin                         989855740                1335 DRRDEVMH            DRRPRODB                           1201 none                                  0 Not Requested       a00:8a45::                    
 admin                        1768947706                 932 test                test                                916 none                                  0 Not Requested       a00:94b6::                    

 WARNING - 1241024 - Possible string truncation in column 1.
 WARNING - 1241028 - Output column defined with warnings.
 WARNING - 1241024 - Possible string truncation in column 9.
 WARNING - 1241028 - Output column defined with warnings.
 WARNING - 1241024 - Possible string truncation in column 10.
 WARNING - 1241028 - Output column defined with warnings.
 OK/INFO - 1241044 - Records returned: [3].
```

As we can see in the last line of `dump.txt` there is a string `Records returned: [3]`. That digit 3 is my target, I want to send a email notification to users having following Lines as Email body:

```
Total Number of Sessions running = 3 

NOTE: This is an automatically generated email, please don't reply to it.
```

After Googling, I have managed to get below method to get it done.

Can anybody please help me out for how to use `sed` or any other method to meet my objective in above script?

```
$ var=Records returned :
echo "Total Number of Sessions running = $var | sed 's/.*://' " > file.tmp 
echo -e "\n" >> file.tmp 
echo "NOTE: This is an automatically generated email, please don't reply to it."  >>   file.tmp 
fi

mailx -s "Subject" emailaddresses < file.tmp
rm file.tmp
```

**NOTE:** `Records Returned...` line will be always the last line in **dump.txt**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use `grep` and a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
$ grep -oP '(\d+)(?=\].s*$)' dump.txt 
3
```

The regular expression above searches for the longest string of numbers followed by `].` and 0 or more spaces until the end of the line. You can combine this with the rest of your email message like so:

```
$ read -r -d '' message <<'EOF'
> Total Number of Sessions running = $(grep -oP '(\d+)(?=\].\s*$)' dump.txt)
> 
> NOTE: This is an automatically generated email, please don't reply to it.
> EOF
$ echo "$message" | mailx -s "Subject" emailaddresses
```

To get that right, type `read -r -d '' message <<'EOF'` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Then, paste or type in `Total Number of Sessions running = $(grep -oP '(\d+)(?=\].\s*$)' dump.txt)` hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> again (as many times as you want blank lines), paste the rest of the message and write EOF to exit.

Answer (score 2):

When your file `dump.txt` exists and is filled as you descripted you can do this with a simple shell oneliner:

`echo -e "Total Number of Sessions running = $(tail -n 1 dump.txt | sed 's/.*\[\([0-9]\)\].*/\1/g')\n\nNOTE: This is an automatically generated email, please don't reply to it." | mail -s "subject" "mail@example.com`"

May I need to explain a little bit:

`tail -n 1 dump.txt | sed 's/.*\[\([0-9]\)\].*/\1/g` prints the last line from the file `dump.txt` and and deletes everything except the digit in the braces `[]`. (in your example: `3`)

This information plus the strings around it are sent to the mail command that reads them from the STDIN and sends a mail to the given address.

Comment: @Chaos..don't know why but its giving no result..when i run `tail -n 1 dump.txt | sed 's/.*\[\([0-9]\)\].*/\1/g' `...getting blank line as an output.

Comment: What is the content of the last line? When you type `tail -n 1 dump.txt`?

Comment: ...a complete blank line..!